# phantomjs is not capturing image for a page which redirects to different page

Tags: phantomjs

I am trying to capture a web page that has redirects(I don't have the actual URL i visit a url then it redirect me to real URL)

For example 
This is the URL i am capturing

[`http://facebook.com/930559626990858`](http://facebook.com/930559626990858)

This redirects User to

[`https://www.facebook.com/kalyani.emandi/videos/930559626990858/`](https://www.facebook.com/kalyani.emandi/videos/930559626990858/)

Phantomjs is not creating image for such links

Here is the code i am using

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://facebook.com/930559626990858', function() {
  page.render('facebook.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

How can i capture URL's that have redirects

**Update**

> Redirecting..._script_path =
>   "WebIDEndpointDispatchController";var
>   uri_re=/^(?:(?:[^:/?#]+):)?(?://(?:[^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?/,target_domain='';window.location.href.replace(uri_re,function(a,b,c,d){var
>   e,f,g;e=f=b+(c?'?'+c:'');if(d){d=d.replace(/^(!|%21)/,'');g=d.charAt(0);if(g=='/'||g=='\')e=d.replace(/^[\/]+/,'/');}if(e!=f){if(window._script_path)document.cookie="rdir="+window._script_path+";
>   path=/;
>   domain="+window.location.hostname.replace(/^.*(.facebook..*)$/i,'$1');window.location.replace(target_domain+e);}});/*=0){throw
>   1;}}si_cj("3 ");}catch(e){si_cj("1
>   \t");window.document.write("\u003Cstyle>body * {display:none
>   !important;}\u003C/style>\u003Ca href=\"#\"
>   onclick=\"top.location.href=window.location.href\"
>   style=\"display:block !important;padding:10px\">Go to
>   Facebook.com\u003C/a>");/*nj4wiNXp*/}}}())/*]]>*/window.location.replace("https://www.facebook.com/kalyani.emandi/videos/930559626990858/");

This is the above script showed in saved html(generated by example mentioned in comments )

Comment: what page is captured with provided code?

Comment: nothing is captured. no file is created. And no error is provided

Comment: add status check to your script like here: https://gist.github.com/AdamSkywalker/d1ba57553b449222d80b

Comment: it most likely fails to open your url

Comment: tried not working and no message in console either

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: version 2.0.0. Ok i'll try that.

Comment: OK, I added the code that saves downloaded html to file and it's clear that facebook just bans the request. This is most likely the reason why phantom fails to render page to image. You can check it by yourself https://gist.github.com/AdamSkywalker/5589a229495d7c09631b

Comment: I tried and it showed both `OK` & `OK2` but didn't create image and created html file

Comment: updated question with the html output.. This is the html which redirects to new page. How can i extract the new url from this and capture the webpage then?

Answer (score -1):

I run a PhantomJs-as-web-service SaaS, and when I run your url through it, it works:

[http://api.phantomjscloud.com/api/browser/v2/a-demo-key-with-low-quota-per-ip-address/?request={url:%22http://facebook.com/930559626990858%22,renderType:%22html%22,outputAsJson:true}](http://api.phantomjscloud.com/api/browser/v2/a-demo-key-with-low-quota-per-ip-address/?request=%7Burl:%22http://facebook.com/930559626990858%22,renderType:%22html%22,outputAsJson:true%7D)

Take a look at this output, the `pageResponses.events` node.  That tells you what is happening when your url is requests.  You'll see that there are page redirects occuring.   PhantomJs is notorious for not handling redirects and AJAX "page complete" properly.

So **to solve your problem**, you'll need to add a delay when rendering.  (the standard example that you are following doesn't handle AJAX content).   A quick and dirty hack would be:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://facebook.com/930559626990858', function() {
     setTimeout(function(){
          page.render('facebook.png');
          phantom.exit();
     },2000
});
```